Синонимизировать метки на тему [меню]
Предлагаю синонимизировать следующие метки:

меню 258 вопросов
menu 292 вопроса

у обеих есть описания.
Основная - меню, так как она на русском.

Для html  будет как-то не очень. Ну и может еще какие случаи. Предлагаю поподробнее изучить имеющиеся вопросы.

@αλεχολυτ, проверил все 54 вопроса с метками [menu] и [html] - они все про меню.

Готово!
updating post history, 300 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 291 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 284 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'menu': [menu] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 542
tag remapping of [меню] and [menu] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
20 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym menu -> меню was approved!

